# Action Editor - Editing Bone.A in one Action alters (undesirably) Bone.A in other Actions

Tags: animation, actions

First time here :).

I'm running into an issue with the Action Editor. I'm not using NLA - seems like overkill for my purposes.

I'm using the Action Editor to author a series of animations for a game character (run, jump, shoot, etc).

In Pose Mode, I rotate the Weapon_Bone for Shoot, and it's getting magically (undesirably) rotated in Jump. I don't want that. I want each action to be unlinked and separate. All actions for the rig are set with 'Fake User' on.

Is this a known issue? Is there a way I can avoid/work around it?

Not sure what else to do, feels like I'm missing something simple?

TIA!

Stephen

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We lack information, maybe show some screenshots or even share your file (the armature only with for example 2 actions that help to see the problem): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Sorry it's super simple. If I edit a bone (by say rotating it) in one Action e.g. Jump, the bone is magically updated in another Action e.g. Shoot. What doesn't make sense?

Comment: That "magical" update is not what I want. Why are "bone edits" being "shared" across actions? Isn't each action its own thing?

Comment: To clarify further. I'm in Pose Mode and I'm rotating a bone in ActionShoot, and it's getting magically rotated in ActionJump.

Comment: What you are probably seeing is that if one action (shoot) keys a bone, and another action doesn't (jump), when you switch from shoot to jump, the bone is left in whatever state is was in during the shoot animation. An action basically mutates a bunch of variables; any variable no mutated is left in its old state. Try clearing all pose bones after switching to get rid of the residual effects.

Comment: Both actions key the bone. How do I "clear all pose bones" after switching? Do you mean Alt R / G / S? And, do you mean before switching?

Comment: Action_Shoot rotates the bone for recoil. Action_Jump rotates the bone for the start of the jump. Super common stuff.

Comment: Well if that's not it, I don't have any other guesses. You should upload a .blend file like moonboots suggested.

Comment: Okay, thanks for trying to help, appreciated.